# WebResponse posting a null string

Tags: java, xml, rest, post, httpwebresponse

I am trying to post a xml from an html text area based from the curl command below

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'xml=<hml>...</hml>' http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/
```

Here is my code so far

```
@Produces("application/xml")
public String validate(@FormParam("xml") String xml) {

    try {
        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/");

                                                  // POST method
        //Posting null for some reason.
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, xml);
        // check response status code
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        // display response
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
        System.out.println(output + "\n");
        return output;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Oops";
}
```

When I run this with an XML that has been tested to work to the webapp I keep getting the null entry response.

I am not sure where to proceed

**EDIT:**
Primary question has been answered below. Bug appears with a + in the xml below is an example. Under the "consensus-sequence block is the "+" with strand. all other enumerations work (-,-1,1)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hml xmlns="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1  http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd"
 version="1.0.1" >

 <!-- 
  MIRING Element 1.1 requires the inclusion of an hmlid.
  hmlid can be reported in the form of an ISO Object Identifier (OID)
  "root" represents a unique publically registered organization
  "extension" is a unique document id managed by the reporting organization.
 -->

 <hmlid root="2.34.48.32" extension="HML.3245662"/>

 <!-- 
  MIRING Element 1.2 requires the inclusion of a reporting-center.
  reporting-center identifies the organization sending the HML message.
  "reporting-center-id" is a unique identifier of the sender.
  "reporting-center-context" reports the context/naming authority of the identifier.
 -->

 <reporting-center reporting-center-id="567"/>
 <sample id="4555-6677-8">
  <typing gene-family="HLA" date="2015-01-13">

   <!-- 
    MIRING Element 3 requires the inclusion of Genotyping information.
    The Genotype should include all pertinent Loci, as well as a Genotype in a standard format.  
    GLStrings can be included either as plain text, or as a reference to a publicly
    available service, such as GL Service (gl.nmdp.org)
   -->

   <allele-assignment date="2015-07-28" allele-db="IMGT/HLA" allele-version="3.17.0">
    <haploid locus="HLA-A" method="DNA" type="02:20:01"/>
    <glstring>
     HLA-A*02:20:01
    </glstring>
   </allele-assignment>
   <typing-method>

   <!-- 
    MIRING Element 6 requires platform documentation.  This could be a peer-reviewed publication,
    or an identifier of a procedure on a publicly available resource, such as NCBI GTR
   -->

    <sbt-ngs locus="HLA-A"
     test-id="HLA-A.Test.1234"
     test-id-source="AcmeGenLabs">
     <raw-reads uri="rawreads/read1.fastq.gz"
      availability="public"
      format="fastq"
      paired="1"
      pooled="1"
      adapter-trimmed="1"
      quality-trimmed="0"/>
    </sbt-ngs>
   </typing-method>
   <consensus-sequence date="2015-01-13">

    <!-- 
     MIRING Element 2 requires the inclusion of Reference Context.
     The location and identifiers of the reference sequence should be specified. 
     start and end attributes are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence.
    --> 

    <reference-database availability="public" curated="true">
     <reference-sequence
      name="HLA-A reference"
      id="Ref111"
      start="945000"
      end="946000"
      accession="GL000123.4"
      uri="http://AcmeGenReference/RefDB/GL000123.4"/>
    </reference-database>

    <!-- 
     MIRING Element 4 requires the inclusion of a consensus sequence.
     The start and end positions are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence (reference-sequence-id)
     Multiple consensus-sequence-block elements can be included sequentially.
    -->

    <consensus-sequence-block reference-sequence-id="Ref111"
     start="945532"
     end="945832"
     strand="+"
     phase-set="1"
     expected-copy-number="1"
     continuity="true"
     description="HLA-A Consensus Sequence 4.5.67">

     <!-- 
      A sequence can be reported as plain text, or as a pointer to an external reference,
      or as variants from a reference sequence.
     -->

     <sequence>
      CCCAGTTCTCACTCCCATTGGGTGTCGGGTTTCCAGAGAAGCCAATCAGTGTCGTCGCGGTCGCTGTTCTAAAGCCCGCACGCACCCACCGGGACTCAGATTCTCCCCAGACGCCGAGGATGGCCGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTACTCTCGGGGGCCCTGGCCCTGACCCAGACCTGGGCGGGTGAGTGCGGGGTCGGGAGGGAAACCGCCTCTGCGGGGAGAAGCAAGGGGCCCTCCTGGCGGGGGCGCAGGACCGGGGGAGCCGCGCCGGGACGAGGGTCGGGCAGGT
     </sequence>

     <!-- 
      MIRING Element 5 requires the inclusion of any relevant sequence polymorphisms.  
      These represent variants from the reference sequence.
      start and end attributes are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence.
      You can see this variant at positions 10 - 15 on the sequence. (945542 - 945532 = 10)
     -->

     <variant id="0"
      reference-bases="GTCATG"
      alternate-bases="ACTCCC"
      start="945542"
      end="945548"
      filter="pass"
      quality-score="95">

      <!-- 
       The functional effects of variants can be reported using variant-effect.  
       They should use Sequence Ontology (SO) variant effect terms.
      -->

      <variant-effect term="missense_variant"/>
     </variant>
    </consensus-sequence-block>
   </consensus-sequence>
  </typing>
 </sample>

 <!-- 
  Multiple samples can be included in a single message.  
  Each sample should have it's own reference-database(s) even if they are identical to other samples' references. 
 -->

 <sample id="4555-6677-9">
  <typing gene-family="HLA" date="2015-01-13">
   <allele-assignment date="2015-07-28" allele-db="IMGT/HLA" allele-version="3.17.0">
    <haploid locus="HLA-A" method="DNA" type="02:20:01"/>
    <glstring>
     HLA-A*02:01:01:01
    </glstring>
   </allele-assignment>
   <typing-method>
    <sbt-ngs locus="HLA-A"
     test-id="HLA-A.Test.1234"
     test-id-source="AcmeGenLabs">
     <raw-reads uri="rawreads/read2.fastq.gz"
      availability="public"
      format="fastq"
      paired="1"
      pooled="1"
      adapter-trimmed="1"
      quality-trimmed="0"/>
    </sbt-ngs>
   </typing-method>
   <consensus-sequence date="2015-01-13">
    <reference-database availability="public" curated="true">
     <reference-sequence
      name="HLA-A reference"
      id="Ref112"
      start="945000"
      end="946000"
      accession="GL000123.4"
      uri="http://AcmeGenReference/RefDB/GL000123.4"/>
    </reference-database>
    <consensus-sequence-block 
     reference-sequence-id="Ref112"
     start="945532"
     end="945832"
     strand="+"
     phase-set="1"
     expected-copy-number="1"
     continuity="true"
     description="HLA-A Consensus Sequence 4.5.89">
     <sequence>
      CCCAGTTCTCGTCATGATTGGGTGTCGGGTTTCCAGAGAAGCCAATCAGTGTCGTCGCGGTCGCTGTTCTAAAGCCCGCACGCACCCACCGGGACTCAGATTCTCCCCAGACGCCGAGGATGGCCGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTACTCTCGGGGGCCCTGGCCCTGACCCAGACCTGGGCGGGTGAGTGCGGGGTCGGGAGGGAAACCGCCTCTGCGGGGAGAAGCAAGGGGCCCTCCTGGCGGGGGCGCAGGACCGGGGGAGCCGCGCCGGGACGAGGGTCGGGCAGGT
     </sequence>
    </consensus-sequence-block>
   </consensus-sequence>
  </typing>
 </sample>

</hml>
```

Thank you

Comment: try removing XML= --data-urlencode '<hml>...</hml>'..something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javadoc of `@FormParam` (emphasis mine):

> Binds the **value(s)** of a form parameter contained within a request entity body to a resource method parameter.

That is, if you invoke your `validate()` method e.g. from cURL like this

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'xml=<hml>...</hml>' http://localhost:8080/validate
```

then the method parameter `xml` will be bound to the value `<hml>...</hml>` on which the `ValidateMiring` service returns a message `XML is null.` (at least to me).

If you, instead, prepend your method parameter with a prefix `xml=` before you post it to the actual web service, you should get a different result:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, "xml=" + xml);
```

Comment: This is great! Question though, while it is accepting the xml is there a reason it is replacing not accepting a "+" in my xml though it is part of the enumeration that is allowed? Saying that the value ', ' is not accepted though it is a "+"

Comment: I just checked with the other enumerations it is only with + that it is not working (other enumerations are -,-1,and 1)

Comment: @Georgrio: Can you provide an example of an XML string containing a '+' character that is not accepted by this web service?

Comment: @Georgrio: I suspect there's a bug in the implementation of their web service. For example, when I upload your XML file to their [Web UI](http://miring.b12x.org/), it gets validated without any problems. Additionally, the error message caused by the allegedly faulty `strand`attribute reads as if the plus sign was dropped somewhere between your client and their XML validator. They seem to have tokenized the error message, that's where the comma has its origin: `The value '' of attribute 'strand' on element 'consensus-sequence-block' is not valid with respect to its' ...