# + sign being dropped from xml when validation occurs

Tags: java, xml, rest, post, sax

up to a previous question I asked here [WebResponse posting a null string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440872/webresponse-posting-a-null-string/38442480?noredirect=1#comment64298290_38442480)

while the answer works for the question a new problem happened. When parsing the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hml xmlns="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1  http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd"
 version="1.0.1" >

 <!-- 
  MIRING Element 1.1 requires the inclusion of an hmlid.
  hmlid can be reported in the form of an ISO Object Identifier (OID)
  "root" represents a unique publically registered organization
  "extension" is a unique document id managed by the reporting organization.
 -->

 <hmlid root="2.34.48.32" extension="HML.3245662"/>

 <!-- 
  MIRING Element 1.2 requires the inclusion of a reporting-center.
  reporting-center identifies the organization sending the HML message.
  "reporting-center-id" is a unique identifier of the sender.
  "reporting-center-context" reports the context/naming authority of the identifier.
 -->

 <reporting-center reporting-center-id="567"/>
 <sample id="4555-6677-8">
  <typing gene-family="HLA" date="2015-01-13">

   <!-- 
    MIRING Element 3 requires the inclusion of Genotyping information.
    The Genotype should include all pertinent Loci, as well as a Genotype in a standard format.  
    GLStrings can be included either as plain text, or as a reference to a publicly
    available service, such as GL Service (gl.nmdp.org)
   -->

   <allele-assignment date="2015-07-28" allele-db="IMGT/HLA" allele-version="3.17.0">
    <haploid locus="HLA-A" method="DNA" type="02:20:01"/>
    <glstring>
     HLA-A*02:20:01
    </glstring>
   </allele-assignment>
   <typing-method>

   <!-- 
    MIRING Element 6 requires platform documentation.  This could be a peer-reviewed publication,
    or an identifier of a procedure on a publicly available resource, such as NCBI GTR
   -->

    <sbt-ngs locus="HLA-A"
     test-id="HLA-A.Test.1234"
     test-id-source="AcmeGenLabs">
     <raw-reads uri="rawreads/read1.fastq.gz"
      availability="public"
      format="fastq"
      paired="1"
      pooled="1"
      adapter-trimmed="1"
      quality-trimmed="0"/>
    </sbt-ngs>
   </typing-method>
   <consensus-sequence date="2015-01-13">

    <!-- 
     MIRING Element 2 requires the inclusion of Reference Context.
     The location and identifiers of the reference sequence should be specified. 
     start and end attributes are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence.
    --> 

    <reference-database availability="public" curated="true">
     <reference-sequence
      name="HLA-A reference"
      id="Ref111"
      start="945000"
      end="946000"
      accession="GL000123.4"
      uri="http://AcmeGenReference/RefDB/GL000123.4"/>
    </reference-database>

    <!-- 
     MIRING Element 4 requires the inclusion of a consensus sequence.
     The start and end positions are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence (reference-sequence-id)
     Multiple consensus-sequence-block elements can be included sequentially.
    -->

    <consensus-sequence-block reference-sequence-id="Ref111"
     start="945532"
     end="945832"
     strand="+"
     phase-set="1"
     expected-copy-number="1"
     continuity="true"
     description="HLA-A Consensus Sequence 4.5.67">

     <!-- 
      A sequence can be reported as plain text, or as a pointer to an external reference,
      or as variants from a reference sequence.
     -->

     <sequence>
      CCCAGTTCTCACTCCCATTGGGTGTCGGGTTTCCAGAGAAGCCAATCAGTGTCGTCGCGGTCGCTGTTCTAAAGCCCGCACGCACCCACCGGGACTCAGATTCTCCCCAGACGCCGAGGATGGCCGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTACTCTCGGGGGCCCTGGCCCTGACCCAGACCTGGGCGGGTGAGTGCGGGGTCGGGAGGGAAACCGCCTCTGCGGGGAGAAGCAAGGGGCCCTCCTGGCGGGGGCGCAGGACCGGGGGAGCCGCGCCGGGACGAGGGTCGGGCAGGT
     </sequence>

     <!-- 
      MIRING Element 5 requires the inclusion of any relevant sequence polymorphisms.  
      These represent variants from the reference sequence.
      start and end attributes are 0-based, and refer to positions on the reference sequence.
      You can see this variant at positions 10 - 15 on the sequence. (945542 - 945532 = 10)
     -->

     <variant id="0"
      reference-bases="GTCATG"
      alternate-bases="ACTCCC"
      start="945542"
      end="945548"
      filter="pass"
      quality-score="95">

      <!-- 
       The functional effects of variants can be reported using variant-effect.  
       They should use Sequence Ontology (SO) variant effect terms.
      -->

      <variant-effect term="missense_variant"/>
     </variant>
    </consensus-sequence-block>
   </consensus-sequence>
  </typing>
 </sample>

 <!-- 
  Multiple samples can be included in a single message.  
  Each sample should have it's own reference-database(s) even if they are identical to other samples' references. 
 -->

 <sample id="4555-6677-9">
  <typing gene-family="HLA" date="2015-01-13">
   <allele-assignment date="2015-07-28" allele-db="IMGT/HLA" allele-version="3.17.0">
    <haploid locus="HLA-A" method="DNA" type="02:20:01"/>
    <glstring>
     HLA-A*02:01:01:01
    </glstring>
   </allele-assignment>
   <typing-method>
    <sbt-ngs locus="HLA-A"
     test-id="HLA-A.Test.1234"
     test-id-source="AcmeGenLabs">
     <raw-reads uri="rawreads/read2.fastq.gz"
      availability="public"
      format="fastq"
      paired="1"
      pooled="1"
      adapter-trimmed="1"
      quality-trimmed="0"/>
    </sbt-ngs>
   </typing-method>
   <consensus-sequence date="2015-01-13">
    <reference-database availability="public" curated="true">
     <reference-sequence
      name="HLA-A reference"
      id="Ref112"
      start="945000"
      end="946000"
      accession="GL000123.4"
      uri="http://AcmeGenReference/RefDB/GL000123.4"/>
    </reference-database>
    <consensus-sequence-block 
     reference-sequence-id="Ref112"
     start="945532"
     end="945832"
     strand="+"
     phase-set="1"
     expected-copy-number="1"
     continuity="true"
     description="HLA-A Consensus Sequence 4.5.89">
     <sequence>
      CCCAGTTCTCGTCATGATTGGGTGTCGGGTTTCCAGAGAAGCCAATCAGTGTCGTCGCGGTCGCTGTTCTAAAGCCCGCACGCACCCACCGGGACTCAGATTCTCCCCAGACGCCGAGGATGGCCGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTACTCTCGGGGGCCCTGGCCCTGACCCAGACCTGGGCGGGTGAGTGCGGGGTCGGGAGGGAAACCGCCTCTGCGGGGAGAAGCAAGGGGCCCTCCTGGCGGGGGCGCAGGACCGGGGGAGCCGCGCCGGGACGAGGGTCGGGCAGGT
     </sequence>
    </consensus-sequence-block>
   </consensus-sequence>
  </typing>
 </sample>

</hml>
```

Which is the sample given for the validator so I know it works. However when I pass it through my restful POST code:

```
@POST
    @Path("/Validate")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String validate(@FormParam("xml") String xml)
    {
        System.out.println(xml);
        try {
            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/");


                                                      // POST method

                                                      ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class,"xml="+xml);
                                                      // check response status code
                                                      if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                                                          throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
                                                      }

                                                      // display response
                                                      String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
                                                      System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
                                                      System.out.println(output + "\n");
                                                        return output;
                                                      } catch (Exception e) {
                                                          e.printStackTrace();
                                                      }

        return "Oops";
    }
```

Everything passes through perfectly fine except for Strand="+" which for some reason drops the + and gets the error message of The value '' of attribute 'strand' on element 'consensus-sequence-block' is not valid with respect to its...'

I tried it with all of strands enumerations +,-,-1,1 and all of them work except for +.

Using the WEB UI (miring.b12x.org) it works perfectly.

Is there something with parsing with SAX that could cause a + to be dropped or any reason a certain enumeration would be dropped?

Thank you

EDIT: Here is the output received:

```
Output from Server .... 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<miring-report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               timestamp="07/19/2016 15:07:31"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/miringreport/1.0/miringreport.xsd">
   <hml-compliant>reject</hml-compliant>
   <miring-compliant>reject</miring-compliant>
   <hmlid extension="HML.3245662" root="2.34.48.32"/>
   <samples compliant-sample-count="4"
            noncompliant-sample-count="0"
            sample-count="2">
      <sample hml-compliant="true" id="4555-6677-8" miring-compliant="true"/>
      <sample hml-compliant="true" id="4555-6677-9" miring-compliant="true"/>
   </samples>
   <fatal-validation-errors>
      <miring-result miring-rule-id="reject" severity="fatal">
         <description>[cvc-attribute.3:, The, value, ', ', of, attribute, 'strand', on, element, 'consensus-sequence-block', is, not, valid, with, respect, to, its, type,, 'null'.]</description>
         <solution>Verify that your HML file is well formed, and conforms to http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd</solution>
      </miring-result>
      <miring-result miring-rule-id="reject" severity="fatal">
         <description>[cvc-attribute.3:, The, value, ', ', of, attribute, 'strand', on, element, 'consensus-sequence-block', is, not, valid, with, respect, to, its, type,, 'null'.]</description>
         <solution>Verify that your HML file is well formed, and conforms to http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd</solution>
      </miring-result>
      <miring-result miring-rule-id="reject" severity="fatal">
         <description>[cvc-enumeration-valid:, Value, ', ', is, not, facet-valid, with, respect, to, enumeration, '[-1,, 1,, +,, -]'., It, must, be, a, value, from, the, enumeration.]</description>
         <solution>Verify that your HML file is well formed, and conforms to http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd</solution>
      </miring-result>
      <miring-result miring-rule-id="reject" severity="fatal">
         <description>[cvc-enumeration-valid:, Value, ', ', is, not, facet-valid, with, respect, to, enumeration, '[-1,, 1,, +,, -]'., It, must, be, a, value, from, the, enumeration.]</description>
         <solution>Verify that your HML file is well formed, and conforms to http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd</solution>
      </miring-result>
   </fatal-validation-errors>
   <validation-warnings>
      <miring-result miring-rule-id="1.2.b" severity="warning">
         <description>The node reporting-center is missing a reporting-center-context attribute.</description>
         <solution>Please add a reporting-center-context attribute to the reporting-center node. You can use reporting-center-context to specify the naming authority of the reporting center identifier.  Reporting-center-context is not explicitly required.</solution>
         <xpath>/hml[1]/reporting-center[1]</xpath>
      </miring-result>
   </validation-warnings>
</miring-report>
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: Added the output from the validator.

Comment: You don’t set the [type](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)) of your WebResource, and I don’t know what the default Content-Type of the request is, but I suspect it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which means `+` is being treated as a space.  If that is the case, changing "xml="+xml to `"xml=" + URLEncoder.encode(xml, "UTF-8")` may solve the problem.

Comment: That would be it! If possible, could you rewrite your answer as a non-comment so I can accept it as the right answer? Also, if you could explain what URLEncoder.encode fully does that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t set the [type](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)) of your WebResource, and I don’t know what the default Content-Type of the request is, but I suspect it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which means `+` is being treated as a space.  If that is the case, changing "xml="+xml to `"xml=" + URLEncoder.encode(xml, "UTF-8")` may address the problem.

The application/x-www-form-urlencoded format is the default format for HTML form submissions, as [described in the HTML 4.01 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).  The [the documentation for the URLEncoder class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) also describes this format.

In that format, a `+` character represents a space, so the `strand` attribute contains a single space.  Except, [the Attribute-Value Normalization section](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize) of the XML 1.0 specification states:

> If the attribute type is not CDATA, then the XML processor MUST further process the normalized attribute value by discarding any leading and trailing space (#x20) characters …

So, that single space is then normalized into the empty string (when all leading and trailing space is removed).  The empty string, `strand=''`, does not conform to the XML schema you are referencing, http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd .

URLEncoder.encode escapes all “reserved” characters, including `+`, as percent-escapes, and then escapes spaces as `+`.  The server expects this format (almost certainly because a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header is present in the HTTP request), and decodes the `+` and percent-escapes back to the original XML.